# Bonita 7 : Custom Widget property type to support JSON data

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

I am trying to create a new **custom widget** in **Bonita 7** and I need a **Property** that can accept **JSON data (not simple array collection)** i.e., I want to assign below data

```
[
        {
        'header1': 'data1-1',
        'header2': 'data1-2',
        'header3': 'data1-3'
        },
        {
        'header1': 'data2-1',
        'header2': 'data2-2',
        'header3': 'data2-3'
        }
    ]
```

I tried all the available property types **(text,choice ,html ,integer,boolean ,collection property)** & I guess nothing works.
Could someone help me to achieve this.

I am trying to create a **Smart-Table** custom widget (https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table) & I want the table data(rows) to be populated using a variable that is of JSON type.

Is there any other way of achieving this.

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry, **collection property type actually works**

This is what I did:

1. In the **CUSTOM WIDGET EDITOR**

1A) created a new property :

```
name : tableDataCollection
Label: TABLE_DATA
Type: collection  (text type also works)
Default value:    (trying to assign JSON data here didn't work for me)
```

1B) In the **Controller** box, use the property **tableDataCollection** defined in step 1A:

```
 $scope.data =  $scope.properties.tableDataCollection; (inside  function ($scope) {})
```

1C) In the **Template** box, use the variable **data** defined in step 1B:

```
 example :  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
```

2) In the **PAGE EDITOR** (FORM EDITOR), if you are using the custom widget created in step 1, you will see a new fields on the right related to your custom widget. In my case it is **TABLE_DATA**

2A) Now, create a new form variable of type JSON.

example : data2Var =

```
 [{
            "header1": "data1-1",
            "header2": "data1-2",
            "header3": "data1-3"
            },
            {
            "header1": "data2-1",
            "header2": "data2-2",
            "header3": "data2-3"
}]
```

2B) Now, Assign the variable created in step 2A to your custom widget field.
in my case, I assigned data2Var to TABLE_DATA

Comment: could you please add details on how you did it ?

Comment: @ttoine : I edited my answer. Please let me know if anything is unclear